# powershell script to move backup files

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell

I want to zip sql bakup files and move from one directory to to another directory within a system using powershell 1.0 can you help me since am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Over at [CodePlex](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) you can get their PowerShell extensions to use their `write-zip` extension.

```
$source = "directory you're zipping from"
$destination = "directory you want to zip to"
Write-zip -LiteralPath $source -OutputPath $destination
```

If you want to remove the .bkp files after you've zip them, you can use `Remove-Item`.
Try using `Get-Help` in PowerShel if you run into issues.